# Is this too broad to be constructive?

Tags: discussion, scope, not-constructive

This question was recently asked and there is some difference of opinion among the moderators as to whether the question is a good fit for SE and what's to be done about it. Here it is:

[How do Christians justify their belief and how do they convince others of their belief?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3704/30)

Is this question a good fit for the format or do we need to do something about it?

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest that the question as it stands is too broad to be a good fit for an SE QnA site.

1. It's a BIG topic. Too big. Basically it's asking "What are Christian apologetics and how are they applied?" I don't think it can be reasonably answered in one question or even in this format.
2. Attempts at summarizing are going to run into wild disagreements. While I respect the person who made it and their views in general, I already radically disagreed with the answer given in a comment. I think it is a religion (and a relationship). Others are going to say it's not. How can we ask a "meta" question about how something is defended when the definition of the thing being defended is already considered not a reasonable question? Basically this means the question will be likely to solicit extended discussion and debate.
3. Everybody that reads the question is going to have a different idea about how how it should be answered. I think the question should be closed in order to curb a rash of answers going ten different directions with some in disagreement, some just with scope differences because of how they read the question or how they personally approach their faith.

It is possible that it could be redacted into a reasonable question, this argument is only a defence of closing the current version (pending improvements).

Answer (score -4):

In contrast to Caleb's views, I don't try to read a question as "basically asking" some broader topic than it is actually asking.  Maybe it's just my background as a programmer, but I have a tendency to read words a bit literally: they mean what they say and not some other thing that they do not say.  The question is a very fundamental one: what is the basis for personal belief and for sharing that belief?  It doesn't need to be made incredibly broad and cover the entirety of apologetics.  That *would* be ridiculous, but thankfully it's not what the OP is asking.

I see it as having here a pretty well-defined question with a simple enough scope that it can be answered well, if we don't artificially try to read a lot more into it than was actually asked.

Comment: Isn't "apologetics" just the term we use for "how we justify our beliefs"? Adding "how do we share them" just throws in the entire scope of missions (applied apologetics). I know you read it and had an answer in mind (a good one at that) but I think everybody that reads it is going to have a different approach because AS WORDED I think it really is trying to ask for what is apologetics  both in theory and application.